# How can i get result from FirstOrDefault method with good performance

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, asp.net-core

I have a list with 10 elements (assume that `List<TestObj> resultList`) and also i have IQueryable (assume that name is resultQueryable) with count 7039. I try to run code below:

```
foreach (var listItem in resultList)
{
   listItem.Amount = resultQueryable.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == listItem.Id).Amount;
}
```

but foreach code spend a lot of time because resultQueryable store 7039 element and FirstOrDefault method return result so late. What can i do for good performance?

Comment: What's happening are 2 things: 1) you're reusing the DB context in a way it's not intended. There are some options to tweak performance: creating a new context and disabling tracking. 2) you should be able to fetch the data from 1 query - this should boost the performance significantly.

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. If you don't want to do that, you should `ToDictionary` `resultQueryable` **before** the loop. Have the ID as the key, and then use `TryGetValue` against the dictionary inside the loop. Your code, as is, executing a DB query for each entry in `resultList`.

Comment: Also have a read of https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/3491721/linq-to-entities---where-in-clause-in-query .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code to just fetch the items we need once, and then work on fetched items:

```
var resultListIds = resultList.Select(li=>li.Id);
var resultSet= resultQueryable.Where(ri => resultListIds.Contains(ri.Id)).ToArray();
foreach (var listItem in resultList)
{
   listItem.Amount = resultSet.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == listItem.Id).Amount;
}
```